# JavaScript onClick addClass

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I am kind of confused why my code doesn't work correctly, I hope You will tell me what I've done wrong.
I want to highlight navigation tab while clicked.

HTML:

```
<header class="mainheader">
  <!-- Obrazek tutaj-->
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a id="a-home" onclick="dodajAktywne(this)" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a id="a-omnie" onclick="dodajAktywne(this)" href="omnie.html">O mnie</a></li>
      <li><a id="a-kurs" onclick="dodajAktywne(this)" href="kurs.html">Kurs</a></li>
      <li><a id="a-kontakt" onclick="dodajAktywne(this)" href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

JavaScript:

```
   function dodajAktywne(elem) {
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    elem.classList.add('active');
}
```

CSS:

```
.active {
    color: blue;
    background-color: #cf5c3f;
}
```

Comment: You should pass `this` to pass the element itself to the function.

Comment: OP code is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8twsdooe/1/). I think he means when he clicks the link doesn't keep the style..

Comment: Without the actual code it is difficult to tell, I assume that you plan to include your <header> tag in every page you have exactly as you have it posted. If this is so, then you problem is that as a link is clicked the page is reloaded and your changes (add class) are discarded. For the future it is best if you would provide a repro using jsfiddle or plunker

Comment: @AlexChar which leads to a conclusion that i.e: `omnie.html` is being followed.

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/8twsdooe/2/) add `return false;` if you dont want to redirect the page

Comment: Are you being redirected to a selected page? If yes, how do you read the URI of the currently opened page?

Comment: Yes I am being redirected to a selected page. I don't read the URL of currently opened page which I assume is the solution. But I don't know yet how to do that :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can simplify your JavaScript to:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/pb95kv32/)

```
function dodajAktywne(elem) {
    // get all 'a' elements
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    // loop through all 'a' elements
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        // Remove the class 'active' if it exists
        a[i].classList.remove('active')
    }
    // add 'active' classs to the element that was clicked
    elem.classList.add('active');
}
```

If you pass the parameter `this` in your HTML to:

```
<header class="mainheader">
    <!-- Obrazek tutaj-->
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a id="a-home" onclick="dodajAktywne(this)" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="a-omnie" onclick="dodajAktywne(this)" href="#">O mnie</a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="a-kurs" onclick="dodajAktywne(this)" href="#">Kurs</a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="a-kontakt" onclick="dodajAktywne(this)" href="#">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**Note: I've changed `href` attribute to `#`, you will have to change it back to your `.html` pages**

---

Alternatively, you can do this without JavaScript, using CSS's `:focus`:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/pb95kv32/1/)

```
a:focus {
    color: blue;
    background-color: #cf5c3f;
}
```

Comment: I have tried both options, none of them are working as intended. Nav buttons just lose their focus.

Comment: @user3703750 - You want the previous button to be active, even if another button is clicked?

Comment: None is active. When I click on another link i.e. home, I want Home button from navigation to be active and highlighted.

Comment: The problem is that my page is redirecting when I click on any tab from navigation. When I've stopped redirecting Your code works perfectly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pb95kv32/2/ This is how I made this. Works correctly now. Thx for help, I'll vote You up :)

Comment: the first solution is what I'm looking for but with reactjs syntax

Answer (score 3):

This code will highlight the navigation tab without needing to include onclick in the HTML, though it doesn't remove the background color if another tab is clicked.

```
    document.onclick = function(event) {
         var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
         target.style.background = '#cf5c3f';
        };
```

https://codepen.io/mdmcginn/pen/BwrNaj/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer.