# CSS display: block doesnt work

Tags: html, css

I made my table hidden with `display: none;` now I want to make it appear with `display:block;` but it doesn't work.

This is my code in css:

```
#ArijsLieve{
    background: #333;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -300px;
    left: 265px;
    cursor: pointer;
}        
#arijslievetable{
    background: #333;
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 701px;
    left: 273px;
    display: none;
}
#ArijsLieve:hover #arijslievetable{ display: block; }
```

My html code:

```
<div id="ArijsLieve">
<h3> Arijs Lieve </h3>
</div>

<table id="arijslievetable">
    <tr>
        <td> Kleuters 3j woensdag </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Kleuters 4j woensdag </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Kleuters 5j woensdag </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Team acro competitie </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I suppose all you need is to override it with `display: block !important; ` but I am not sure if I understood your question correctly...

Comment: you want to display a table as a block instead of as a table?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sibling selector:

```
#ArijsLieve:hover ~ #arijslievetable{ display: block; }
```

Comment: is it posibol to add one more thing to it? i tryed this but it didnt work.
#ArijsLieve:hover ~ #arijslievetable ~ #arijslievefototable { display: block; }

Answer (score 3):

The table is the adjacent sibling of the div, not its descendant.

You need an adjacent sibling combinator (`+`) not a descendant combinator ().

Additionally, a table should be `display: table` not `display: block`.

Comment: is it posibol to add one more thing to it? i tryed this but it didnt work. #ArijsLieve:hover ~ #arijslievetable ~ #arijslievefototable { display: block; }

Answer (score 0):

try this `#ArijsLieve:hover + #arijslievetable{ display: block; }`
If you want to be able to hover over #ArijsLieve you should delete `top:-300px`

Answer (score -1):

You will probably need to use Javascript and need an action.  So on click you will want to show your table I assume.  Here is a good resource for this idea: [JavaScript onClick addClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959219/javascript-onclick-addclass)

What is happening is when you say display none it is hiding it and you need Javascript to replace that class with another class that reads display block.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There's no need to use javascript for this.

Comment: Sorry the question is confusing, first off he asks to display: none and then he wants to display: block.  why not just remove display:none?

Comment: He wants the `#arijslievetable` to show when `#ArijsLieve` is hovered.

Comment: I see missed the hover action item.