# How to apply a class to a list item using JS or jQuery without grabbing by id and keeping active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm using a CMS that doesn't allow me to apply an onclick on the a tag or use an onclick. So it basically outputs in code like the following:

```
<ul class="ul-class" id="ul-id">
 <li class="nav-items"><a href="1">Something1</a></li>
 <li class="nav-items"><a href="2">Something2</a></li>
 <li class="nav-items"><a href="3">Something3</a></li>
 <li class="nav-items"><a href="4">Something4</a></li>
 <li class="nav-items"><a href="5">Something5</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I need to be able to do is apply a class showing an underline on the link that's been clicked that then leaves if another link has been clicked. Unfortunately I cannot get the class to stay present with the click.

I've tried this: [JS Onclick Add Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959219/javascript-onclick-addclass)

But the OP was using an onclick to latch onto.

What I've ended up with is this:

```
$(".nav-items").click(function (e) {
$(this).addClass("nav-active").siblings().removeClass("nav-active");
 });
```

Then for the CSS I have:

```
a.nav-active{
 border-bottom: 5px solid green;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 }
```

The border pops up but leaves immediately. Is there something wrong with the code or do I need to put something else in to make the border permanent unless clicked elsewhere?

Comment: It should also navigate to the link mentioned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like:

Note: You have to use `.nav-active` instead of `a.nav-active` because your `.nav-active` is `<li>` and an `<a>`

```js
$(function() {
  $(".nav-items").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); /* To prevent redirect of <a> */
    $(".nav-items").removeClass("nav-active"); /* Remove the class to all nav-items */
    $(this).addClass("nav-active"); /* Add the class to clicked nav-items*/
  });
});
```

```css
.nav-active {
  border-bottom: 5px solid green;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul-class" id="ul-id">
  <li class="nav-items"><a href="1">Something1</a></li>
  <li class="nav-items"><a href="2">Something2</a></li>
  <li class="nav-items"><a href="3">Something3</a></li>
  <li class="nav-items"><a href="4">Something4</a></li>
  <li class="nav-items"><a href="5">Something5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Happy to help @Jake

Answer (score 0):

I had to reverse your CSS (to `.nav-active a` instead of `a.nav-active`) and add `e.preventDefault();` to the jQuery, but otherwise it seems to be working. It wouldn't hurt to remove the class first before adding it, so change

```
$(this).addClass("nav-active").siblings().removeClass("nav-active");
```

to

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass("nav-active");
$(this).addClass("nav-active");
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach with plain JavaScript

```
var myItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".nav-items")); // make array from NodeList
myItems.forEach(navItem => navItem.addEventListener("click", event => {
    myItems.forEach(maybeSelectedBefore => maybeSelectedBefore.classList.remove("nav-active"));
    event.target.classList.toggle("nav-active", true);
});
```